# Assigning a variable within a class with value of a method

Tags: c++, class, struct

Is there a way to assign a variable within a class with a value of a class method?

I was trying the example below, but it is obviously not working. Is there a correct way of doing this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace :: std;

class rectangle
{
    public:
        rectangle(double h, double w) {
            height = h;
            width = w;
        };

        double area(void) {
            return height*width;
        };

        double myarea = (*this).area();

    private:
        double height, width;
};

int main(void) {
    rectangle r(2.5, 3);
    cout << "Area is: " << r.area() << endl;
    cout << "Area is: " << r.myarea << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result

```
Area is: 7.5
Area is: 0
```

Comment: Interestingly, `MSVC` reproduces your result but `clang-cl` give the desired answer (7.5) for the second output.

Comment: I am using g++ compiler on win10

Comment: Do that in your constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that member variables are initialized **in the order they are declared** within the class. Also, your constructor creates the object **before** you have actually initialized `width` and `height`, as you do your initial assignment in the *body* of the constructor, rather than in an initializer list. Thus, when `myarea` is initialized (in your code), `width` and `height` have not yet been set.

To fix this, you can re-order the members and move the initialization of `width` and `height` into a list:

```cpp
class rectangle {
private:
    double height, width; // These will NOW be set before "myarea" is calculated
public:
    rectangle(double h, double w) : height{ h }, width{ w } {
        // Any assignments done here will be AFTER initialization of "myarea"
    }
    double area(void) {
        return height * width;
    }
    double myarea = area();
};
```

Also, you don't need the complex `(*this).area()` syntax - just `area()` will do.

EDIT: Another thing to remember is that the setting of `myarea` by calling the `area()` function will *only* be done once (at object creation); if you change either `width` or `height` later, you won't (automatically) change `myarea`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Coming from Python it is good to know these subtleties :) Obvious question is if I would pass argument to a method and then assign the result of this method to `myarea`, will it reflect the changes. Easy to try out...

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Yes - you can make *explicit* changes to `myarea` (in member functions) at any time, and such changes will 'stick'.

Comment: Even if this is now logically well-behaving, this kind of code design is an accident waiting to happen. It might be a good idea to mention alternative patterns for _initializing_ the `myarea` member, e.g. by a utility (`static` member / free function) `computeArea(double h, double w)` function that can be invoked in the member initializer list of the `rectangle` ctor as part of explicitly initializing the `myarea` member, however using the provided `h` and `w` ctor arguments rather than the `height` and `width` members (that may or may not have been initialized, based on their order of decls).

Comment: @dfri I agree that this code is not the best design pattern, and that there are many better alternatives. However, as I see it, the OP was simply asking whether or not their technique to assign `myarea` is valid C++, and why their code wasn't working. I think I addressed those issues adequately. In this particular code, there would be no real need for the `myarea` variable *per se* - a simple call to the `area()` member would suffice.